Double Free Error In Swift concurrentPerform
I have the following code for a sparse matrix times a vector. In the sparse matrix, the number of nonzero elements per row is stored, alongside the index in the array of elements at which the first element of that row occurs. These are used to ENSURE that no element of the output vector is written two by multiple threads at once. This code works fine when building without optimisations or when building in debug mode. However when I said the optimisation level to -Ofast, I get a double free error.
Any ideas on what I might have missed?
func parallelVectorMultiply(vector: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
    guard space == vector.space else {
        fatalError("Number of columns in the matrix must match the size of the vector.")
    }
    
    var outputElements = [T](repeating: T(0), count: space.dimension)
    
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: space.dimension) { row in
        
        let start_idx = row_first_element_offsets[row]
        if start_idx == -1 { return }
        let end_idx = start_idx + nonzero_elements_per_row[row]
        var rowSum = T(0)
        for i in start_idx..<end_idx {
            rowSum = rowSum + values[i].value * vector[values[i].col]
        }
        
        outputElements[row] = rowSum
    }
    
    return Vector(elements: outputElements, in: space)
}

I expect no error. In the equation for matrix A times vector X:
AX = Y

Where:

In my code, I compute this sum then store the result to the corresponding element in the output array.
There should be no two threads that free up a single element of the array concurrently.

You might also be interested in the Accelerate framework, which has functions for multiplying arrays of ints, floats or doubles.

Array is not thread-safe. Thus, outputElements is not thread-safe. I know you say, “There should be no two threads that free up a single element of the array concurrently”, but the fact remains that Array simply is not thread-safe. And when you violate thread-safety, you can manifest all sorts of different problems, so I would not put stock in the particulars of any error/crash you received.
Try turning on TSAN temporarily and it may identify the problem. (It does not always, but it is much more reliable than trying to actually manifest the race-related problem.)
If you are going to use this non-thread-safe Array to gather the results, you have to synchronize your access to it (e.g., in high-performance scenarios, such as this, I might reach for a lock, such as OSAllocatedUnfairLock), e.g.:
import os.lock

And
let lock = OSAllocatedUnfairLock()

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: space.dimension) { row in
    …

    lock.withLock {
        outputElements[row] = rowSum
    }
}


You might also consider leveraging a library that has already optimized these sorts of vector operations. It will get you out of doing these low-level calculations yourself. For example, see Using vDSP for vector-based arithmetic. Or, the broader Accelerate framework has a variety of other options, too, so check out the documentation. And if deaing with sparse matrices, BLAS has a series of matrix-vector operations.
